# Split special char character

Tags: c#, split

I have this string that is delimited with char 1 character:

```
3/1k
```

this js script may help to see the string

```js
var s="3/1k";
alert(s);
```

I tried with

```
string[] s1 = Str.Split(new Char[] { (char)1 },StringSplitOptions.None);
string[] s2 = Str.Split((char)1);
string[] s3 = Str.Split('');//copy and paste of (char)1
string[] s4 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split( Str((char)1).ToString());
```

I'd like to split it with delimiter  (char 1)

So I should get an array with

```
s[0]="3/1";
s[1]="";
s[2]="";
s[3]="k";
```

How can I do it with C#?

Comment: It's unclear. Why it should contain two empty elements in the desired array?

Comment: i want to split ascii 1 (SOH) instead of ascii 49.

Comment: Please can you present your input string in such a way that we can see where the SOH characters are. [I can't reproduce a problem with splitting that character](https://dotnetfiddle.net/THl5b2).

Comment: I've seen your reply to Rehan, and incorporated that into my Fiddle. Are you trying to split whilst retaining the SOH character?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use '1' instead of (char)1

```
 public static void Main(string[] args){
     string str = "3/1k";
     string[] v = str.Split('1');
     foreach(string i in v)
         Console.WriteLine(i);
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: "3/1k" is actually concatanation of "3"+"/"+"1"+((char)1).ToString()+((char)1).ToString()+"k"
SOH character does not appear this text lines

Answer (score 0):

Both of the first two suggestions you suggest work fine for me if I start with:

```
var Str = "3/1\u0001\u0001\u0001k";
```

It would seem that perhaps U+0001 is not actually present in the compiled string. If you are putting control characters into source (rather than e.g. reading them from a file) then it is better to escape them as per C# character escapes, rather than depend upon unprintables in the C# file.